# Convert response from server (JSON object) to string in extjs

Tags: json, spring-mvc, extjs4

*In our code, the parameters from the Ext JS page are passed to the Spring 3 controller where we have the business logic. Then in the controller, the response object is set using getWriter.write and response is retrieved in the Ext JS page. 
Problem : While decoding the response, Firebug shows an error on using Ext.util.JSON.decode so we had to use Ext.decode instead to decode our response from the server. But Ext.decode gives a value: object Object. I need to convert it into String or format. 
Controller code :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login.htm",method = RequestMethod.POST)
     @ResponseBody
     public void validateCredentials(@RequestParam("user") String user,
            @RequestParam("password") String password,HttpServletResponse response) {
        boolean flag = false;
        String resultString = null;





        try {
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html, charset=utf-8");


            if (user.equals(password)) {


                flag = true;
                resultString = "{success:true}";
            } else {


                flag = false;
                resultString = "{success:false}";
            }

            response.getWriter().write(resultString);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
Ext JS Login form :
Ext.onReady(function(){


    function submit(button,event){


               var uname=Ext.getCmp('user').getValue();
             alert("1"+uname);
                var passWord=Ext.getCmp('password').getValue();

             Ext.Ajax.request({
                   url: 'login.htm',
                   method :'POST',

                   params: {
                       user:uname,
                       password:passWord
                    },
                   success: function(result,request) {
                      var jresp = Ext.JSON.decode(result.responseText); 
//Ext.JSON.decode stores object Object in jresp. Our requirement is converting jresp to String or boolean
                      console.log('Success'+jresp); 



                   },
                   failure: function(response, request) {
                       var jresp = Ext.JSON.decode(result.responseText);
                       console.log(jresp.error);
                      console.log('server-side failure with status code 8 ' + response.status);
                   }
                });





           }




     var myform = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
            title:'Login form',
            frame:true,
            width:400,
            height: 250, 

            url:'login.htm',
            method:'POST',
            renderTo:'div1',
            items:[
                   {
                       xtype:'textfield',
                       fieldLabel:'user',
                       inputType:'user',
                       allowBlank:false,
                       minLengthText:'3',
                       id:'user',
                       name:'user'
                   },
                   {
                       xtype:'textfield',
                       fieldLabel:'password',
                       inputType:'password',
                       allowBlank:false,
                       minLengthText:'3',
                       id:'password',
                       name:'password'
                   }
                   ],
                   buttonAlign:'center',
                   buttons:[
                            {
                                text:'reset',handler:function(){myform.getForm().reset();}
                            },
                            {

                                text:'Login',
                                handler: submit
                            }

                            ]       

                   });






});
```

Comment: Can you post a response you're getting? If it's JSON you should be able to use JSON.Decode

Answer (score 0):

> While decoding the response, Firebug shows an error on using
>   Ext.util.JSON.decode so we had to use Ext.decode instead to decode our
>   response from the server.

you were getting error because you were using wrong object in ExtJS4 its Ext.JSON.decode to encode data not Ext.util.JSON.decode, you are having this confusion because ExtJS3 was having Ext.util.JSON.decode for parsing JSON strings, but yeah failsafe way will be to use Ext.decode which is shorthand for correct function in ExtJS3 and ExtJS4 both

> But Ext.decode gives a value: object Object. I need to convert it into
>   String or format

this is true because you are generating response like `"{success:true}"` so when you parse that JSON string you will get something like this

> data = {'success' : true};

so you can get your boolean value by using `data.success`

so your final code will look like this

```
var jresp = Ext.JSON.decode(result.responseText); 
console.log('Success'+jresp.success);
```

one more thing you are generating response in spring mvc using this string

> resultString = "{success:true}";

which is not a valid json string, so you need to enclose key of the object in double quotes something like this

> resultString = "{\"success\":true}";

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass a Model instance including all the fields you need in the javascript (ExtJs), you can use jackson to convert your model do JSON.

Just declare your converter in appContext:

and including the jackson jar.

You can also put the success and message in the model. For simplicity use a abstract ExtJsModel with success and message fields and make all your models extend that same model.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the response like this to extjs . Then use extjs decoder.
Here is the code.

var jresp = Ext.util.JSON.decode(result.responseText);
console.log(jresp.success);

"""{success:true}"""

If you console like this.
console.log('Success'+jresp.success);

java-script always give object.So don't use this.